# Run long running stored procedure in SQL with no output result, no need to stop application , just need flag to application 'running process' only

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a huge amount of data in my tables and to extract results I used a stored procedure from it takes nearly 60 minutes.

Until it's done, my application is frozen or in wait.

My question is: I need to call the stored procedure from C# code and I do not need any output from it.

I handled all code in backend once done email got send.

I need only stored procedure should start execute and give alert to user, that once procedure is done mail will get to you.

Please describe how to run that procedure in the background without blocking my application in wait for user.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question? An applications can load data for 1hour and thats ok. You can check DB tables to see what is status of your application's session and send a mail if it succeeded. Now, if in some case application doesnt know when the sql is finishing off, may be you can check application log to see why polling stopped.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: My question is simple,that i dont need output for application,i handled email procedure backend once record insert into table auto procedure is happens,also handle log in db,

Comment: Just i need that from application sp should start its operation and application should not get stop.backend functionalities auto done. i used sql server 2012.asp.net mvc application

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution which I have used successfully is to create a SQL Agent job that runs your stored procedure.

From your application you then just start the Agent job using [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which returns immediately; SQL Agent then runs your procedure asynchronously with no additional involvement from your application.